# How to convert double to char[] by myself in c++?

Tags: c++, format, printf, type-conversion, double

Since i have to convert lots of double to char[] very fast, after step into `sprintf`, i found that `_cfltcvt_l` did the real conversion work, and before `_cfltcvt_l` is called, it has many `switch`,`case`,`validate`...function that i don't really need, so i want to convert double to char[] by myself.

I want to get the same result as `sprintf(c,"%16.9E",d);`does, for example:

d=49.9999999995;  -->  c={"5.000000000E+001"}

d=2.5323867855e+298;   -->  c={"2.532386786e+298"}

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fast_sprintf(char* c, double d)
{
    int i = 0, e = 0, n = 0, flag = 0;//flag=0E+;1E-

    if (d < 0)
    {
        c[i++] = '-';
        d = -d;
    }
    while (d >= 10)
    {
        d /= 10;//here is the problem
        e++;
    }
    while (d < 1)
    {
        d *= 10;
        e++;
        flag = 1;
    }
    int v = d, dot;
    c[i++] = '0' + v;//the integer part
    dot = i;
    n++;
    c[i++] = '.';
    d -= v;
    while (d != 0 && n < 10)
    {
        d *= 10;
        v = d;
        c[i++] = '0' + v;
        n++;
        d -= v;
    }
    if (d != 0)
    {

        if (d * 10 >= 5)//rounding
        {
            int j = i - 1;
            c[j]++;
            while (c[j]>'9')
            {
                c[j] = '0';
                if (j - 1 == dot)
                    j--;
                c[--j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (n < 10)
        {
            c[i++] = '0';
            n++;
        }
    }

    c[i++] = 'E';
    c[i++] = (flag == 0) ? '+' : '-';
    if (e >= 100)
    {
        int tmp = e / 100;
        c[i++] = '0' + tmp;
        e -= (tmp*100);
        c[i++] = '0' + e / 10;
        c[i++] = '0' + e % 10;
    }
    else if (e <= 9)
    {
        c[i++] = '0';
        c[i++] = '0';
        c[i++] = '0' + e;
    }
    else
    {
        c[i++] = '0';
        c[i++] = '0' + e / 10;
        c[i++] = '0' + e % 10;
    }
    c[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char c[20];
    //double d=49.9999999995;
    double d=2.5323867855e+298;

    sprintf(c,"%16.9E",d);
    cout<<c<<endl;

    fast_sprintf(c,d);
    cout<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when d=2.5323867855e+298, c={"2.53238678**5**e+298"} instead of c={"2.53238678**6**e+298"}

That's because after this loop:

```
//before loop, d=2.5323867855000001e+298
while (d >= 10)
    {
        d /= 10;//here is the problem
        e++;
    }
//after loop, d=2.5323867854999969
```

d loses its precision, the last digit **5** becomes **4999969**.

So how can i fix my code or is there a better way to implement another `sprintf(c,"%16.9E",d);`?

Thanks.

Comment: And by the time you write code for all the corner cases, taking care of loss of precision, etc.  you wind up with ... `sprintf()` (or worse).

Comment: If you need precision you definitely can't rely on floating point numbers: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: So i wonder how `sprintf` works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not necessarily.  Knowing that he's targeting a `"%E` format, with exactly 10 digits, can avoid a lot of `if`s, `switch`s, etc.  Some of which may be in tight loops; knowing that he needs exactly 10 digits, in fact (and no more) means that he can probably completely unroll the loop, with no loop condition, and that he can do everything in integer arithmetic (on `int`; the generic algorithm traditionally requires integer arithmetic on values which don't fit in an `int`).

Comment: [Convert double to string quickly observing given precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34744591/995714), [C++: what is the optimal way to convert a double to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1313988/995714), [double to string without scientific notation or trailing zeros, efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15165502/995714), [Converting double to char* in C++ with high performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749585/995714)

Answer (score 0):

The reference document for these conversions is &ldqou;How to
Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately”, by Steele and
White; it was published in PLDI '90, and is available on line
from the ACM digital library.

Given that you're interested in speed and a fixed format, with
10 digits, a somewhat simpler approach might be to scale the
number to the range `[1E9...1E10)`, then use `modf` to extract
the integer part, incrementing it if the fractional part is
greater than `0.5`.  Then convert the integral part to an `int`,
and generate your digits from that.  The amount you've scaled it
by should give the exponent.

Finding the value to scale it by could be a critical issue;
using `log10` is an obvious solution, provided it's accurate in
your library.  Otherwise, you could use a table of powers of ten
(calculated once, off line), and a second table, indexed by the
exponent (see `frexp`) into this table.  Using this technique,
you'd have at most two comparisons to find the correct scaling
factor.  (Functions like `modf` and `frexp` are generally very
fast, because they manipulate the bit pattern of the number
directly; if they don't, it's easy to do what you need by
manipulating the bit pattern of your `double` yourself.)

This is, of course, just a general suggestion of an approach.
The devil is in the details, and it will take a lot of care to
get all of the corner cases right.  But there is a good chance
that it will be faster than `sprintf`, precisely because it
*only* does this one particular format.