# Convert double to string quickly observing given precision

Tags: c++, sdl, ostringstream

I have a `C++` program using `SDL`. During rendering, I need to draw some graphics components. I sometimes need to convert `double` variables, rounded to one decimal, to `std::string`.

For this, I'm currently using a `ostringstream` object and it works fine.

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << x;
```

However, I'm wondering if this way of converting variables is a good idea with regards to performance.

I've tried to round the `double` variables with `std::to_string(std::round(x * 10) / 10))`, but it didn't work -- I still got output like `2.500000000`.

- **Is there another solution?**
- **Does `ostringstream` incur a heavy cost?**

Comment: considering performance: the `ostringstream` will use a `locale` which invokes some overhead, otherwise if you re-use a single `ostringstream` during your render call (single allocation / growing of the internal buffer) then there should be no more overhead than `sprintf`

Comment: *but it didn't work.* you should elaborate on that.

Comment: Just in case you really *mean* "it did not work", you *did* compile with a C++11 compiler, or your compiler set to (at least) C++11 standard, did you?

Comment: I did compile with a C++11 compiler. Didn't change anything. I still had my variable set to 2.500000000 (for example).

Comment: @Q3SanD: Well, the `std::setprecision` turns this question on its head for sure. Deleted my answer as it turned out to be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does this mean I am left with this solution? Can't I use the solution I've tried with `std::round` and then use `std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify the precision with `std::to_string` as it is a direct equivalent to `printf` with the parameter `%f` (if using `double`).

If you are concerned about not allocating each time the stream, you can do the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string convertToString(const double & x, const int & precision = 1)
{
    static std::ostringstream ss;
    ss.str(""); // don't forget to empty the stream
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << x;

    return ss.str();
}


int main() {
    double x = 2.50000;

    std::cout << convertToString(x, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(x, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(x, 3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs ([see on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19433f1ac46eb8cb)) :

> 2.50000
>
> 2.5
>
> 2.500

I didn't check the performance though... but I think you could even do better by encapsulating this into a class (like only call `std::fixed` and `std::precision` once).

Otherwise, you could still use `sprintf` with the parameters that suits you.

---

Going a little further, with an encapsulating class that you could use as a static instance or a member of another class... as you wish ([View on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/286dc75ab68a4043)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

class DoubleToString
{
public:
    DoubleToString(const unsigned int & precision = 1)
    {
        _ss << std::fixed;
        _ss << std::setprecision(precision);
    }

    std::string operator() (const double & x)
    {
        _ss.str("");
        _ss << x;
        return _ss.str();
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream _ss;

};


int main() {
    double x = 2.50000;

    DoubleToString converter;

    std::cout << converter(x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Another solution without using `ostringstream` ([View on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/588faf37195b41f9)) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

std::string my_to_string(const double & value) {
  const int length = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%.1f", value);

  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[length + 1]);
  std::snprintf(buf.get(), length + 1, "%.1f", value);

  return std::string(buf.get());
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    std::cout << my_to_string(argc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_to_string(2.5156) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: It's still using `ostringstream` (no choice I guess) but it's much cleaner than my solution. I won't mark it as answer but I'll upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: @Q3SanD I added another solution without `ostringstream`, but I'm not sure it is more efficient, you should run a bench.